# How to persist data between OnGet() and OnPost() calls

Tags: c#, .net, razor-pages

First Razor-pages application I'm developing so I'm a bit confused.

When the OnGet() function is called there is a call to the SpotifyAPI to get the playlists for the current user and assign them to a variable. This variable then needs to be checked against the selected values on the UI on the OnPost() call.

Problem is, when OnPost() gets called the PlaylistsToLook variable is now null.

Is there a way of preserving the value between the two calls?

This is the cshtml.cs

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Models.AppDbContext _context;

        public CreateModel(Models.AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            PlaylistsToLook = PlaylistRequestService.GetUserPlaylists(_context);
        }

        public void OnPost(string[] playlistsToLook)
        {
            foreach (var playlistId in playlistsToLook)
            {
                PlaylistRequest.PlaylistsToLook.Add(PlaylistsToLook.First(x => x.id.Equals(playlistId)));
            }
            _context.PlaylistRequests.Add(PlaylistRequest);

            PlaylistRequestService.ProcessPlaylistRequest(PlaylistRequest, _context);
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public List<SpotifyPlaylist> PlaylistsToLook { get ; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public Models.PlaylistRequest PlaylistRequest { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the cshtml

```
@page
@model SpotifyPlaylistCurator.Pages.PlaylistRequest.CreateModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreatePlaylist";
}

<h2>Create a Playlist</h2>
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PlaylistRequest.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="PlaylistRequest.Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PlaylistRequest.Duration" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="PlaylistRequest.Duration" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PlaylistRequest.PlaylistsToLook" class="control-label"></label>
        @{
        int cnt = 0;
            foreach (var playlist in Model.PlaylistsToLook)
            {
                if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                {
                    @:</tr><tr>
                }
                @:<td>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           name="playlistsToLook"
                           value="@playlist.id" />
                            @playlist.name
                @:</td>
            }
        }
      </div>
    <div></div>
    <input type="submit" name="Create a Playlist" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i created a default Razor pages and below are the changes i did to persist data in Session

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        // ADD SESSION
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        });
        // ADD MEMOERY CACHE
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //app.UseCookiePolicy(); I HAD TO COMMENT THIS LINE TO MAKE IT WORK

        // ADD USESESSION
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

And in the controller:

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        var s = HttpContext.Session.GetString("MyData");
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            this.HttpContext.Session.SetString("MyData", "Test Data Here");
        }            
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        var s = HttpContext.Session.GetString("MyData");
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            this.HttpContext.Session.SetString("MyData", "Test Data Here");
        }
    }
```

That's a very simplified example but you can read more about it at:
[Session State in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/session-state)

Answer (score 0):

The `TempData` property of the PageModel should work for this.

The cookie based version is enabled by default but if the list is greater than 500bytes, you'll want to use the session based version:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // snip

    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
        .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

    services.AddSession();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // snip

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tempdata